# OnClick Event not Captured

Tags: forms, javascript

I am currently developing a module in Drupal. I made a button that show a dialog box whenever it's clicked.

```php
function myid_init() {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path("module", "myid") . "/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js");

  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path("module", "myid") . "/js/myid.js");   
}

function myid_menu() {
  $items = array();
  
  $items['admin/settings/myid'] = array(
    'title' => 'myid Settings',
    'description' => 'Configuration options for the myid module',
    'page callback' => 'myid_admin_settings',
    'access callback ' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
  );
  
  return $items;
}

function myid_admin_settings() {
   return drupal_get_form('myid_settings_form');
}

function myid_settings_form() {
  $form = array();

  $form['myid_registrar_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => '...',       
    '#attributes' => array(
      'id' => 'myid_registrar_button',         
    ), 
  ); 

  return $form;
}
```

The JavaScript code is the following

```js
$(function(){
  $('#myid_registrar_button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    alert("Eww");             
  }); 
});
```

Whenever I click a button, it refreshes and it doesn't show anything.

It seems the event is not captured. The console doesn't show errors.

What am I missing?

Comment: Go through following https://www.drupal.org/node/756722

Comment: Try after adding your js code inside `document.ready`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be adding JQuery like that.  It's automatically included in core, so you don't need to include it yourself.  To stay up with the latest JQuery version, install the [jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module.

For your JS file, this should work:

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.myid.registrar_button = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
            $('#myid_registrar_button').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); 
                alert("Eww");             
            }); 
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You don't want to do that.  Drupal.behaviors holds all the code to run on page load.  You can change it to Drupal.behaviors.myid_registrar_button, but make sure it's under Drupal.behaviors.